# Is it “payment on/to/of something”?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-of

Which preposition should be used in the following situations — *on*, *to* or *of*?

> 1. payment on/to/of something.
> 2. Here is the money to/of it.

Comment: Adpositions depends on context...

Comment: This question does not seem of broad appeal. This is partly because the second example wouldn't take either of those two prepositions. Is there a general rule you are seeking out?

Answer (score 4):

*Payment* is a nominalization of the verb *pay*, and therefore it inherits properties 
of the verb, including some prepositional usages. And *pay* is a particularly complex verb 
(it's the short verbs that tend to cause problems in English; they're really common and 
develop all kinds of idioms and special usages).

*Pay* is part of the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) (CTF), which means that it involves

- not just **two** Noun Phrases (NPs)
  (Subject and Direct Object NPs, as in a transitive clause like *Mary ate lunch*),
- or even **three** NPs
  (Source/Subject, Trajector/Direct Object, and Receiver/Indirect Object,
  as in a bitransitive clause like  *Mary bought Bill lunch*),
- but **four** NPs, each with a very specific semantic role in this frame.
  **And** specific prepositions to mark each NP with in a nominalization:
  *a payment **of** $10 **by** Mary **to** Bill **for** lunch*.

These NPs (also featured in [other CTF usages](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), like *buy, spend,* and *sell*) are:

1. the **Payer**, subject of *pay*, and prototypically a human NP
2. the **Money**, direct object of *pay* and one the two trajectors (i.e, things that move)
3. the **Payee**, indirect object of *pay*, also prototypically human
4. the **Commodity**, the other trajector, which takes the preposition *for*.

With *pay*, the action starts with the Payer possessing the Money and the Payee possessing the Commodity; *paying* means moving the Money to the Payee and the Commodity to the Payer, so that the possession relations are reversed at the end of (and as a result of) the action.

This is fine with a verb, since subject, direct object, and indirect object all have places
in the structure, and can even participate in the Dative Alternation:

- *Bill paid Marian $100 **for** the lamp.*
- *Bill paid $100 **to** Marian **for** the lamp .*

So that's two prepositions accounted for: *to* marks the indirect object of *pay* (in this case, the Payee) and *for* marks the Commodity; these preposition choices are inherited by *payment*:

- *a payment to Marian for the lamp*

But nouns can't have subjects or direct objects, either, so more prepositions are necessary.

When a transitive verb is nominalized (the rules are different for intransitives, but *pay* is, if anything, **super**-transitive), *of* marks the direct object of *pay* (i.e, the Money), and *by* its subject (the Payer):

- *a payment of $100 by Bill to Marian for the lamp*

which is unwieldy but grammatical and unambiguous.

There are other ways to do this; for instance, the subject can possess the nominalization:

- *Bill's payment of $100 to Marian for the lamp*

And they can appear by themselves

- *a payment by Bill*
- *a payment for the lamp*
- *a payment to Marian*
- *a payment of $100*

or in any combination -- one rarely needs to specify all four NPs with a nominalization, in context.

Comment: What does "NP" mean?

Comment: Noun Phrase: pronoun, noun, noun with modifiers, compound nouns, noun clause -- all NPs. Thanks for the suggestion; I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Thought it was NP-Complete.

Comment: I’ll bet you five bucks this is another CTF. Or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your use of "sth". But, maybe this will help in any case:

"Payment is due **on** the 5th."

"Payments are made **to** ABC Corp Ltd."

"I made a payment **of** $400."

"Here is the money **for** it."

So:

"Here is the $400 **for** this month's rent."

Comment: Essentially any preposition can be used here depending on context. Payment could also be due *by* the 5th, *through* ABC Corp, *against* $400 [of a debt], *with* it [i.e. something else I am also presenting].

Comment: "Sth." (sometimes w/o the period) is simply a common formulaic abbreviation for indefinite _something_; "s.t" and "s.o" are also common.

Comment: Right. But these abbreviations should be avoided in all but the most informal of contexts, since there are many people (like Erin, apparently) who do not recognize their meaning.